# Reactor Flux how to publish in parallel

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given such example

```
 Flux.range(0, 10)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println(i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .subscribe();
```

I thought it would publish all items in parallel and in different threads. But it actually processed in single thread sequentially.

```
0 parallel-2
1 parallel-2
2 parallel-2
3 parallel-2
4 parallel-2
5 parallel-2
6 parallel-2
7 parallel-2
8 parallel-2
9 parallel-2
```

I know we can use `.parallel().runOn(Schedulers.parallel())`, but I want to know how to achieve this with publishOn and subscribeOn. Otherwise would subscribeOn and publishOn always execute on single thread? then what is the purpose of Schedulers.parallel()?

Comment: Switching threads is a costly operation. Reactor uses technics like *work stealing* to avoid unnecessary change of thread at execution. If ParallelFlux is designed for parallel tasks, Flux is designed for *concurrency*, and that's slightly different. Concurrency tries to handle many execution contexts independently of (even with few) resources (threads). In this regard, Fluxes might decide to switch threads only at critical key points (indepedendant subscriptions for example).

Comment: Thanks, so with Flux most of time ".publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())" would be same as ".publishOn(Schedulers.single())", which is running on a separate single thread? Do you have an example when Flux would decide to use more than 1 thread with ".publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())"?